# How To Get Page Public Content Access?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Ok I've been having a hard time getting approved for page public content access.

I'm developing a facebook app that let's you search for facebook pages.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gc-Ah_To-xg

Sort of like this.

Here are my questions:

- How do I get approved for PPCA when I can't make a screencast of the app in action without actually having PPCA?
- Is it possible to search for pages without PPCA?
- Will hardcoding work?

Comment: How do you search for pages with PPCA?

Comment: According to my quick test in Graph API Explorer, that feature appears to be testable perfectly fine, as long as your app is in dev mode.

Answer (score 0):

If just to answer your questions:

1. simulate it - hardcode info, main idea is to show how info would be used
2. yes, you could have "Page Public Metadata Access" feature turned on
3. yes

Also not forget to use App token instead of User and Page tokens.

My story was next, maybe it would help you: I was fighting with App review for almost 2 weeks... what I did is just shown how I use information which I would receive from search ('Page Public Metadata Access') in mentioning searched pages in posts, also very important was to show that Mentioning feature is working (by mentioning my own page).